# how to avoid open chrome with SmartShopSave?

Tags: google-chrome

when I open chrome a website come in, but I can't find any software or plugins about SmartShopSave? what is it and how to drop it?

[SmartShopSave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vk1J.png)

1.My chrome has no suspicious  extension
2.I don not find any suspicious process

but a message arise when I click setting

[setting information images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8VUJ.png)

and I find two files using everything and I delete them

http_www.smartshopsave.com_0.localstorage

http_www.smartshopsave.com_0.localstorage-journal

but I fail when I open chrome www.smartshopsave.com still exists

how do I find that program ?

Answer (score 0):

have you checked your browser extensions with dev mode activated?

I also recommend that you review your instlled software. In fact, if you do not have any extension in chrome, but you have adware, than it is not an extension but a software that is running on your machine.. There is software for example, that installs itself and then infects all browsers. Even if you delete a supposed extension, it will keep coming back. So in case chrome remains clean, here is what you can do:

1. Revise your files and folders to see if there is anything that you don't remember or have not installed.
2. Check your System Monitor to see if there is any suspicious process or service running. If there is, attempt to kill it, find the source of said process and delete or remove it, so it doesn´t go back on. You
3. You might also consider installing a Virus Scanner. There are some on the store to download for free. Generally be CAREFUL when doing any online website scan. In most cases it doesn't work and chances are good it will infect you even more.

Comment: I have been tried your tips but smartshopsave still exists~